# svg path hover not working till clicked - others work fine

Tags: svg, raphael, jquery-svg

As I move the mouse over 'cells' all of them work on page load but one needs to be clicked first. As all of the paths are created in the same way and the path in question is not the first nor the last generated I have no idea what's the cause.

[my project](http://danu2.it.nuigalway.ie/09101916/qtipdemo2/)

The path in question is for 'Co. Donegal'. This is the one at the TOP, left-side. On page load the qtip displays correctly but no fade-in occurs until clicked. This is not the case with the other paths.

Any idea? tia.

Comment: How odd. Somebody gives a 2½ year old question a negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Donegal needs a value: 'notSelected', attribute in paths.js